Custom modules are not working even after adding them to __init__.py
I am trying to get all the odoo projects from my other system to a new system and while doing so, I am facing a problem during moving my files.
When I add previously created custom_addons folder to newly created odoo workspace and add it's path to addons-path, "ImportError: No module named hr_payroll_leave" error is thrown even when hr_payroll_leave directory does exits in the custom_addons folder and the terminal log shows:
 odoo@payrolluat:~/odoo-irctc-8.0$ python openerp-server
2024-09-04 07:38:29,573 9179 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0
2024-09-04 07:38:29,573 9179 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/payrolluat/workspace/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/addons', u'/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/custom_addons', '/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/addons']
2024-09-04 07:38:29,573 9179 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2024-09-04 07:38:29,573 9179 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2024-09-04 07:38:29,573 9179 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2024-09-04 07:38:29,632 9179 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2024-09-04 07:38:36,772 9179 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2024-09-04 07:38:36,987 9179 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2024-09-04 07:38:37,119 9179 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2024 07:38:37] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2024-09-04 07:38:37,121 9179 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 304, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 292, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/service/server.py", line 294, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1298, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1319, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/openerp/modules/module.py", line 80, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/payrolluat/workspace/odoo-irctc-8.0/custom_addons/hr_payroll_irctc/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import hr_payroll_leave
ImportError: No module named hr_payroll_leave

This is only happening with 2 of my files and other files are working just fine! When I comment these 2 files from init.py the error disappears and odoo works perfectly but when comment is undone then the error returns.

There is more to it than this! I'm not sure but there is something wrong with the configuration I guess. Odoo is unable to read the directories in the custom addons folder and throws 'QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login
' error. I sometimes able to get pass this error by removing each directory and then bringing them back, in that case I'm stuck with my previous problem. I also tried to delete those file and then recreate them which makes it work, but if I somehow manage to get to App List page then total features including 'Update App list' are not present.
